# ConfigObj using configspec with enumerated sections

Tags: python, ini, specifications

I'm developing an application and would like to use `ConfigObj` to parse an `.ini file`. I would like to have some default values on a configspec.spec file. I don't know if there's a way to have some enumerated sections, such as `User1, User2,...UserN,` with some values which should have the same default for all these sections (for example, `Name=''` as a default for all the `Users`) and some which should depend on the section (for example `User_ID=N` for a specific User `UserN`).

Thanks.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please read up on
[how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and provide a
[minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.